# Complex mapping of curve

Tags: plotting, complex

I have a curve in the complex plane (a unit circle), and I want to plot the curve with a complex function applied to it ($f(z)=\sqrt{z}$) How do I go about doing that?

I know how this can be done analytically, I just want a more general method that can be applied to different curves.

Comment: `Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[Sqrt[z]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Mesh -> 10]]`

Comment: @cvgmt thanks, I managed to use this to solve my problem. how can I change the x,y axes? PlotRange is not allowing me to change them independently

Comment: `Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[Sqrt[z]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Mesh -> 10, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> {True, True}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.08], 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, MeshStyle -> Brown, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, BoundaryStyle -> Blue]]`